# How did we combine a sequence to commit branches in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, regex-negation, rules, validationrules

I'm facing syntax issue

```
($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^[A-Z][0-9][-_]SPRINT[0-9]+/i)
($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^SPRINT[0-9]+/i)
($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^[A-Z]SPRINT[0-9]+/i)]
```

(SPRINT-branch name) can you please help me to combine these split sequence into single command line

Comment: I think you can make the first parts optional `^([A-Z]([0-9][-_])?)?SPRINT[0-9]+`

Comment: [rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev" || ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ "^([A-Z]([0-9][-_])?)?SPRINT[0-9]+")
    when: always
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "dev" || ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH !~ "^([A-Z]([0-9][-_])?)?SPRINT[0-9]+")
    when: never ] -I'm using like this but the pipeline didn't triggers for [R1_sprint3] branch @Thefourthbird

Comment: The pattern matches for `R1_sprint3` but you have to make the pattern case insensitive. See https://regex101.com/r/3pIpC5/1 or use a character class A-Za-z and all variations for the word sprint like `^([A-Za-z]([0-9][-_])?)?[Ss][Pp][Rr][Ii][Nn][Tt][0-9]+`

Comment: Now its working @Thefourthbird

Comment: Did you use `/i` or the longer pattern with all the variations?

Comment: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH !~ (/^([A-Z]([0-9][-_])?)?SPRINT[0-9]+/i)) This is the command , I used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
^([A-Z]([0-9][-_])?)?SPRINT[0-9]+
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Start a group

  - `[A-Z]`  Match a single char A-Z
  - `([0-9][-_])?` Optionally match a digit 0-9 and either `-` or `_`
- `)?` Close the group and make it optional
- `SPRINT[0-9]+`

The code can look like

```
($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH !~ (/^([A-Z]([0-9][-_])?)?SPRINT[0-9]+/i))
```

See the matches in this [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/3pIpC5/1).

Comment: fine thank you! can you explain "i" ? @The fourth bird

Comment: @CyrilI The `/i` flag makes the pattern case insensitive, so it will match `SPRINT` and `sprint` `SpriNt` etc..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72216766/how-do-i-use-docker-environment-variable-in-entrypoint-array-issue-facing-in-ku?noredirect=1#comment127596994_72216766